# PHP sticky form code within form building echo statement

Tags: php, forms, echo, builder, sticky

My form builds a test from a text file and builds the answer selection using echo statements as below:

```
function buildTest()
    {
        /*if((file_exists("files/questions.txt")) && ((file_exists("files/answers.txt")) && (filesize("files/questions.txt")!=0)) && (filesize("files/answers.txt") !=0))
        {*/
            $questionArray = array();
            $questionArray = file("files/questions.txt"); //populate the questions array from a file
            $answerArray = array();
            $answerArray = file("files/answers.txt"); //populate the answers array from a file
        //}

        for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
        {
            echo "<div class=\"question\"><br />";
            echo "<h3>Question #" . ($i + 1) . "</h3><br />";
            echo $questionArray[$i] . "<br /><br />";

            switch ($i)
            {
                case 0:
                    echo "<input type='radio' name='questionOne' value='True'" . if (isset($questionOne) && $questionOne=="True") echo "checked" . "?>/> True<br />";
                    echo "<input type='radio' name='questionOne' value='False' <?php if (isset($questionOne) && $questionOne=="False") echo "checked";?>/> True<br />";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    echo "<input type='radio' name='questionTwo' value='false' /> Blood, Water, Fire, Wind and Earth<br />";
                    echo "<input type='radio' name='questionTwo' value='false' /> Diamond, Ice, Water, Fire and Wind<br />";
                    echo "<input type='radio' name='questionTwo' value='Metal, Water, Wood, Fire and Earth' /> Metal, Water, Wood, Fire and Earth<br />";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    echo "Answer: <input type='text' name='questionThree' />";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    echo "<input type='radio' name='questionFour' value='True' /> True<br />";
                    echo "<input type='radio' name='questionFour' value='False' /> False<br />";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    echo "<input type='radio' name='questionFive' value='Goat' /> Goat<br />";
                    echo "<input type='radio' name='questionFive' value='false' /> Rat<br />";
                    echo "<input type='radio' name='questionFive' value='false' /> Dragon<br />";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    echo "Answer: <input type='text' name='questionSix' />";
                    break;
                case 6:
                    echo "<input type='radio' name='questionSeven' value='True' /> True<br />";
                    echo "<input type='radio' name='questionSeven' value='False' /> False<br />";
                    break;
                case 7:
                    echo "<input type='radio' name='questionEight' value='false' /> Horse<br />";
                    echo "<input type='radio' name='questionEight' value='false' /> Fox<br />";
                    echo "<input type='radio' name='questionEight' value='Pig' /> Pig<br />";
                    break;
                case 8:
                    echo "Answer: <input type='text' name='questionNine' />";
                    break;
                case 9:
                    echo "<input type='radio' name='questionTen' value='True' /> True<br />";
                    echo "<input type='radio' name='questionTen' value='False' /> False<br />";
                    break;
            }
            echo "</div>";
            echo "<br /><hr />";
        }
```

The above shows in case 0 two of the methods I've tried to complete this problem.

However, neither of these present the solution. How would I make my input fields sticky in the form building echo statements?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry, `make input fields sticky`, I'm not sure what you mean. Are you asking how to set the property `checked` on the input element given a conditional match using a ternary operator within an echo statement?

Comment: I know how to make sticky fields - it's because the HTML is built with php echo statements that I can't make them work by simply inserting the normal PHP code to make them sticky.

Comment: Ohgodwhy - I misread what you were trying to ask me about - in school, we refer to forms that retain their values when submitted in php as a "sticky form" - it simply means that any field already filled in (checked, written, or otherwise) retain whatever value the user put in when postback occurs if the form is not submitted (so if there is an error such as the entire form wasn't filled out, the form is not cleared on submission). So what I am trying to accomplish relates to that, but since the html is built with php echo statements, it's making it tricky.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use an `if` block to check if `questionOne` is true or false, then act accordingly?

Also, for the `false` option in case 0, you're using `<?php` inside of PHP. The consequence of this is that it's trying to echo that bit of PHP, then it flips out when it gets to the quotes around `False`.

Comment: I am simply trying to make the fields sticky, meaning that when the submit button is pressed when the form is not complete, the user is posted a msg telling them to complete it, but the fields do not lose the answers already filled in by the user. The rest of the code will be written - this is the only thing I'm trying to figure out - how to be able to echo the form in this way, but also echo the sticky fields. If the form were all HTML and I wasn't trying to build it with PHP, this would be easy, but since the HTML is built from PHP code, it's tricky.

Comment: It's not bad. All of your HTML inputs have names, and the names are the keys used for the variables in the POST array when the form gets submitted. What you need to do is submit the form to a PHP script that validates the elements in the POST array, and if any of the inputs fail to validate, POST them back to the original form page and use the POST array to repopulate the form values. To save from having to do two POST requests, you can just have the form page submit to itself, then run validation checks on that same page if and only if `$_POST` is set.

Answer (score 0):

When php processes a form, checked radio buttons and checked check-boxes result in the $_POST variable of that element to have the value of 'on'.  So if the user didn't complete the form to the script's satisfaction and you want to keep the check-boxes and radio buttons checked you need to see what $_POST elements came through with the value 'on' and in those cases you'll need to included checked='checked' in the html input.

for example, using:

if($_POST['elementA']=='on') $stickifierA="checked='checked'";

will cause the html input:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='elementA' <?php echo $stickifierA;?>>
```

to be checked if they checked it on their last (failed) attempt to fill out the form.

You can use a foreach loop to check everything and create appropriate php variables to echo out in each input element.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have some confusion about - (1) what is happening as regards PHP and your data. (2) How to make it do what you want.

I have looked at 'questionTwo' and provided some code that will hopefully help you to 'get some handles' on what is happening.

First: here is some code that has 'sticky values' for 'questonTwo' and you can run and play with:

[Codepad - Viper-7 : Q26806928/php-sticky-form-](http://codepad.viper-7.com/DQvWzi)

Explanation:

1) Every individual radio button, in a group, **must** have a **unique value**. It is the 'value' that is returned in the '$_POST' array. If two radio buttons have the same **value** then you cannot know which one was selected.

2) when you are generating the HTML code to output the 'radio button', which you know the **unique** value of, you need to check in $_POST to see if you have a matching value. If so then output 'checked' and the browser will mark it as selected.

That is all the code i provided does:

If 'var_dumps' $_POST when it is provided so you can see the code working.

Oh, don't forget to 'view page source' in your web browser to see what code it actually received.

Play with code. Hopefully it will become clearer what is happening.

```
<?php // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26806928/php-sticky-form-code-within-form-building-echo-statement

// This is the code for 'QuestionTwo'

// Run it and inspect the source code to see what is happening.

/*
 * Please don't let someone look at the 'page source' and see the answers.
 *
 * <input item1 --- false
 * <input item2 --- false
 * <input item3 --- value
 *
 *  is a clue as to the correct answer.
 */

/*
 * To re-select the 'user selected' input item then the 'input items' must have unique values
 * so that you can output 'checked' on the correct item when displaying it.
 */

// example:
$questions = array();

$questions['questionTwo'] = array('Q2_A1'  => 'Blood, Water, Fire, Wind and Earth',
                                   'Q2_A2'  => 'Diamond, Ice, Water, Fire and Wind',
                                   'Q2_A3'  => 'Metal, Water, Wood, Fire and Earth',
                            );

$answers = array();
$answers['questionTwo'] = 'Q2_A2'; // for example

/*
 * If there was some selected input then it will appear in the $_POST array...
 * It MUST have a unique *value* so that we can identify which item the
 * user selected.
 */

// display the input so you can see what is happening

/* debug */ if (!empty($_POST)) {
/* debug */ var_dump('Post array is:', $_POST);
/* debug */ }

// use PHP as a templating language...
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>sticky-form-code</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="" method='POST'>
<div>
    <?php foreach($questions['questionTwo'] as $answerCode => $answerText): ?>
        <input type='radio' name='questionTwo' value="<?= $answerCode ?>"

             <?php if (!empty($_POST['questionTwo'])): // user selected answer to this question? ?>
                <?php if ($_POST['questionTwo'] === $answerCode): // check if matches this entry? ?>
                    checked
                <?php endif; ?>
             <?php endif; ?>
            ><?= $answerText ?><br />
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>

<!-- check the answer if provided -->
<?php if (!empty($_POST['questionTwo'])): // is there a selected value in $_POST? ?>
     <div>
        <?php if ($_POST['questionTwo'] === $answers['questionTwo']): // match? ?>
         correct!
        <?php else: ?>
         sorry...
        <?php endif ?>
     </div>
<?php endif; ?>
 </div>
 <div>
     <input type='submit' value='Go For it!'>
 </div>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```